# Blank result for String concatenation in foreach

Tags: powershell

There might not be the best way but what is wrong with this code. Why do i get blank result from $str in the foreach loop, whereas if it try to concatenate individual cells i get the right result.

```
$csv = import-csv -Path "C:\Users\abc\csv4script\TEST.csv" -Header 'IPs' 
$str = ''
$x = 1

foreach ($cell in $csv.){

    if ($x -le 4000){

    $str = $str + ", " + $cell.IPs
        if ($x -eq 4000){
        $x = 1}
        $str = ''
    }
$x = $x + 1

}
$str
#    $str = $str + $csv[1].IPs + ", " + $csv[2].IPs
$str
```

Comment: How does your csv file look like? I see a typo in your foreach loop header: remove the dot after `$csv`.

Comment: Because the last executed command on `$str` variable in `foreach` loop is `$str = ''`. Maybe correcting indentation  could make it obvious…

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have a value because you misplaced a '}' character.

`$x = 1}`

Move it to after `$str = ''`

```
    $x = 1
    $str = ''}
```

Also as Thomas pointed out, remove the period after $csv variable in your foreach statement, it should be like: `foreach($cell in $csv)`

Also if you want to increment a value,
`$x++` is quicker and easier to read than `$x = $x + 1`

Lastly, as you have it, if your list has more than 4000 IPs the $str variable will empty out.